# datename sql function not showing the correct day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I went online and saw for example that 03 Nov 2011 is Thursday and 04 Nov 2011 is Friday. I used the function

`SELECT datename (dw, 04-11-2011)` on my server and it says Saturday instead of Friday. How can I set it up to display correctly? Or what am I missing?

**EDIT**:
Thank you all for your inputs. However, most of you pointed out the format I am using and not the fact that it isn't set up correctly. Someone posted (and think deleted his comment) of this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx .

so, I used `set datefirst 1` and to get 4th of November i used `select datename(dw, '2011-11-04')`

Comment: Is 04-11-2011 4th novemer or 11th april? Better use non-ambigous data formats ('2011-11-04' should do).

Comment: April 11 2011 was a Monday. Nov 4 2011 was a Friday.

Comment: And (looking one more time) you missed quotation marks around date constant. Currently you are searcing datename() for int number 4-11-2011 = -2018...

Comment: And if you're wondering why that's a Saturday: the datetime type in SQL Server is based from 1 Jan 1900. If you provide an integer as a date--in this case -2018--it's taken as being the number of days difference from that date. 2018 days before (because it's negative, so you're going backwards in time) 1 Jan 1900 was 23 June 1894, which was a Saturday.

Comment: Also, re. your new question, you can tell by trying `select cast ('04-11-2011' as datetime)` that your date string is being interpreted as 11 April, not 4 November.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use ISO standard date formats, so you know what date you are getting.  Either:

```
select datename(dw, '2011-04-11')
```

or

```
select datename(dw, '2011-11-04')
```

(Or, because the above formats *are* subject to one internationalization setting where they can be misinterpreted, you can leave out the hyphens so they are unambiguously in the YYYYMMDD format.)

Also, enclose date constants in single quotes.

Comment: Yeah, it's the "enclose date constants in single quotes" in this case. Otherwise it's `-2018` which is a Saturday. :)

Comment: thanks for this, but in order for this to work people which have this problem also have to check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx

Comment: @viorelmunteanu . . . `datename()` returns a string.  It *is* affected by internationalization, but that is just whether "Sunday" is spelled "Dimanche", "Sonntag", "Domenica", and so on.  You are confusing this with `datepart()`, which returns a number.

Answer (score 1):

1 Use single double for date values

2 In SQL Server use unambiguous date format YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

```
select datename(weekday, '20110411') as day_name
```